# Angular extend instead of for in loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently using this in an angularjs decorator

```
for (var key in $delegate) {
    proxy[key] = $delegate[key];
};
```

Can I replace it with this, or could there be unforeseen side effects? Are they functionally equivalent?

```
angular.extend(proxy, $delegate)
```

... also, does it make a difference that `proxy` has been declared as a function

```
var proxy = function(){ /* ... */ }
```

everything in js is an object anyway right?

Comment: Have you tested `angular.extend`? Did it work?

Comment: you can see implementation [angular.extend](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L323)